# Can every bijection of natural numbers be defined with a closed form formula

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I am interested in the existance of closed form formulas for bijections on natural numbers.

With the term *closed form* is lose. Any information on formulas that represent permutations on N are welcomed. The following are some additional questions:

1. Can any permutation be represented with a formula for elementary function on real numbers? (or finitly many different such formulas for finitly many different cases)
2. Can any permutation be expressed just using finitly many cases and formulas from peano arithmethics?
3. What if we include all injective functions?

**EDIT:** As noted by @arturo-magidin, the set of formulas over a finite sign is countable, therefore 2. is false.

**EDIT** Formulas could be derived from an uncountable alphabet. (For example real numbers with $+$ and $\cdot$ signs. ).

Comment: The set of bijections from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself is uncountable. The set of formulas is countable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok, I this answers 2. What about 1.? We can use real numbers in formulas.

Comment: There are still only countably many. Formulas are finite, from a countable alphabet.

Comment: I allow uncountable alphabet. (for exapple, all real numbers + standard operations on numbers + varialbex).   {x -> rx | r is real number} is a set of uncountably many formulas encoding different functions. (ofc only a countable subset are bijections on natural numbers).

Comment: Unless your formula is allowed to contain infinitely many symbols, then allowing an uncountable alphabet doesn't make any difference. Can you say a bit more about the context of your question?

Comment: The number of bijections on an n element set is n!  When n tends to infinity we get the number of bijections on natural numbers. How is it uncountable then?

Comment: There are many ways to encode a function between natural numbers into a real number, you need to specify your set of operations, otherwise the question is very loose...

Comment: @fweth yeah, the question is intented to be very loose. I cannot define "closed form" withouth limiting the answer to the point where the answer would be trivial. This is a big handicap for the autistic tensions on SE, but i do not see any other way around it. I dont know of any closed form formulas for bijections, so therefore i cannot define it well.

Comment: @RobArthan allowing uncountable signature most definetly makes a difference. If you just asign a sybol f to each bijection F, you get a set of formulas $x \mapsto f(x)$, which represents all the bijections. (Ofc that is not really the set i am looking for.)

Comment: Assuming that your operations $f:\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$ are bound by a primitive recursive function $f':\mathbf{N}^n\to\mathbf{N}$, i.e. if $|x_i|\le x'_i$ and $x'_i$ is natural then $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\le f'(x'_1,\dots,x'_n)$.  Then the compositions of those functions are also bound by some primitive recursive function and even with freely chosen real parameters, if my thinking is correct, you can't represent a bijection between natural numbers growing faster than any primitive recursive function.  Can anybody confirm my idea?

Comment: Even when you replace primitive recursive by Turing computable I think you could construct a similar contradiction, by choosing some busy beaver like bijection...

Comment: @fweth yeah that sounds good to me..